# Modal editar cakephp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

Estou fazendo um CRUD tudo na minha INDEX porém estou com problema na partes do modal do bootstrap.
Fiz um botão EDITAR onde recebe id mas quando eu clico ele sempre trás o modal vázio.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" class="btn btn-default"  role="button" href="editar/<?=$cliente['Cliente']['id'];?>">Alterar</a>
```

minha controller:

```
public function editar($id = null) { 
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('<div class="pull-right"><div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Erro entre em contato com o suporte.</strong></div></div>'));
    }
    $cliente = $this->Cliente->findById($id);
    if (!$cliente) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('<div class="pull-right"><div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Erro entre em contato com o suporte.</strong></div></div>'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

        $this->Cliente->id = $id;

        if ($this->Cliente->save($this->request->data)) {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('<div class="pull-right"><div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Cliente atualizado com sucesso.</strong></div></div>'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } 
    }
    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $cliente;
    }
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque os códigos dentro do blocos try/catch, para ver qual erro é lançada pela Exception

```
public function editar($id = null) { 

    try {

        //code

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        exit('Error: '. $e->getMessage());

    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {

        $this->set('error_alert', $e->getMessage());

    }

}
```